# Infiinte loading with Next 13

Tags: next.js

I am experimenting with Next 13 and am trying to understand the best solution to create infinite loading

The first 20 items I want to be rendered in the HTML, for SEO benefits, then one the use scrolls to the end of the list it loads more items

So the initial load should be done as a server component I take it, then somehow I need to use a client component to perform the infinite requests

In next 12, rightly or wrongly I would have populated a useState with the data from the server passing in the props, then simply had a function on the client that would perform another, but I am lost with the whole server / client components at the moment

Any help as to the best direction to take will be greatly appreciated.